# HTML 5 Input date not showing the value specified

Tags: c#, html, date, asp.net-core, razor

NET Core** project and in one of my pages to edit a record the `<input type="date">` is not showing me the value I'm passing it when I create the view in Razor.

This is my Razor code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <i class="input-group-text fa fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewPriceList.PriceFrom, 
                     new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", 
                           @Value = Model.NewPriceList.PriceFrom })
</div>
```

And this is what I can see in the Google Chrome developer tool thats been created as HTML

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The Obwiązuje od field is required." 
       name="NewPriceList.PriceFrom" type="date" 
       value="2/15/2019 12:00:00 AM">
```

But for some reason its not rendering correctly and this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need specify the [rfc3339 format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.NewPriceList.PriceFrom , 
    "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
    new { 
        @type= "date",
        @class = "form-control"
        @value = Model.NewPriceList.PriceFrom
    }
)
```

Or if you just want to use the model to render the value, you don't have to specify a `@value=`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.NewPriceList.PriceFrom , 
    "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
    new { 
        @type= "date",
        @class = "form-control"
    }
)
```

Or simply use `InputTagHelper`:

```
<input asp-for="NewPriceList.PriceFrom" class = "form-control" >
```

The `InputTagHelper` will choose the right format automatically for you if you use a [`[DataType(DataType.Date)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute?view=netcore-2.2)
 attribute annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Format the date to ShortDate. A DateControl doesnt like time of the day :

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true"
       data-val-required="The Obwiązuje od field is required."
       name="NewPriceList.PriceFrom" type="date"
       value=@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()>
```